# kubernetes petset on google cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running a kubernetes cluster on google cloud(version 1.3.5) .
I found a [redis.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/pets) 
that uses petset to create a redis cluster but when i run kubectl create -f redis.yaml i get the following error :
error validating "redis.yaml": error validating data: the server could not find the requested resource (get .apps); if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

i cant find why i get this error or how to solve this.

Comment: Probably your kubectl version isn't 1.3, yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PetSet is currently an alpha feature (which you can tell because the `apiVersion` in the linked yaml file is `apps/v1alpha1`). It may not be obvious, but alpha features are not supported in Google Container Engine.

As described in [api_changes.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/devel/api_changes.md#alpha-beta-and-stable-versions), alpha level API objects are disabled by default, have no guarantees that they will exist in future versions, can break compatibility with older versions at any time, and may destabilize the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `PetSet` with some success, for example https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-mysql-cluster, in zone `europe-west1-d` but when I tried `europe-west1-c` I got the aforementioned error.

Comment: Note: PetSet will be disabled. See my updated answer to stackoverflow.com/questions/39245230/petset-on-gke-could-not-find-the-requested-resource

Answer (score 0):

Google just enabled Alpha Clusters for GKE as announced here: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/alpha-clusters

Now you are able (but not SLA covered) to use all alpha features within an alpha cluster, what was disable previously.