# petset on GKE: could not find the requested resource

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to experiment with PetSet on GKE.
I have a 1.3.5 Kubernetes cluster on GKE, but PetSet does not seem to be activated.

```
    > kubectl get petset
   Unable to list "petsets": the server could not find the requested resource
```

Do I need to activate v1alpha1 feature on GKE ?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163685/kubernetes-petset-on-google-cloud/39170065

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `PetSet` in zone `europe-west1-d` but got the error you're seeing when I tried in zone `europe-west1-c`.

Update:

Today, September 1, I got an email from Google Cloud Platform announcing that PetSet was "accidentally enabled" and will be disabled on September 30.

> Dear Google Container Engine customer,
>
> Google Container Engine clusters running Kubernetes 1.3.x versions accidentally enabled Kubernetes alpha features (e.g. PetSet), which are not production ready. Access to alpha features has already been disabled for clusters not using them, but cannot be safely disabled in clusters that are currently using alpha resources. The following clusters in projects owned by you have been identified as running alpha resources:
>
> Please delete the alpha resources from your cluster. Continued usage of these features after September 30th may result in an unstable or broken cluster, as access to alpha features will be disabled.
>
> The full list of unsupported alpha resources that are currently enabled (and will be disabled) is below:
>       Resource    API Group
>       petset  apps/v1alpha1
>       clusterrolebindings     rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1
>       clusterroles    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1
>       rolebindings    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1
>       roles   rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1
>       poddisruptionbudgets    policy/v1alpha1

Comment: Now officially supported on "temporary clusters": https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/alpha-clusters