# Will dynamically provisioned disks be deleted when PetSet is disabled

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

As I wrote in the answer to [petset on GKE: could not find the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245230/petset-on-gke-could-not-find-the-requested-resource), GKE had support for PetSet in `europe-west1-d` but will revoke it by September 30th.

We're using PetSet. How can we keep these services up, provided we don't need to scale up using PetSet? Most importantly, will our persistent disks (`*-dynam-pvc-*`) survive or will they be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they did was delete the PetSet resource and keep the pods running. This means that next time such a pod died for whatever reason there would be no replica set to re-create them. Disks were not deleted.